# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed, Runing container binary as host binary

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, containers

I am going to run an executable inside docker container on the host machine as host machine  binary command.

For example nodejs. I can run nodejs something like below inside the container

```
docker exec -it node:20-alpine node ./something.js
```

But what I want is that I should be able to add the container executable to my host machine PATH variable and use it without any additional docker commands. Is that even possible.

in his case I am trying to use volumes like below

sudo docker run -it -v /docker/bin/:/usr/local/bin/ -d node:20-alpine

If I use this without volume part it is running but with volume it is throwing the error below

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

My questions is.

Is there any solution in this case?

What does this error message mean?